Split flap variant
Reading about this Q&As, how would a split flap behave if it acted like a solid, with no real split, but a thick trailing edge?
Mostly wondering what happens between a) and c) and influence of that reflex airfoil looking shape.
Not sure if position b) increases lift at all?
At position d) is it equivalent to a split flap?
Between d) and e) it looks like a zap flap, chord increase yet camber decrease, so deploying further may not increase lift anymore?
Wondering if position e) has flow reattaching to flap?



Intriguing idea, and thanks for the animation!  I'm looking forward to a good answer from the aero pros, but my hunch is that it ought to perform somewhere in the middle of split and fowler flaps at full deflection.  However, there would be a big drag penalty at half flaps, so intermediate settings wouldn't help take-off performance.

Can the animation be paused?  Or replaced with a few still images from zero to full deflection?  I find it hard to type even a comment nevermind a full answer while my eyes get constantly yanked back to the picture.

Wow... now the animation is so slow I sat there looking at it wondering what animation y'all were talking about...

All of your flaps, starting with position b, will add lift, the more the further back they are positioned. Again, I will use Sighard Hoerners book Fluid Dynamic Lift to support my point. In Figure 9 of chapter 5 he plots the added lift as a function of flap position:

Your most rearward flap is a Zap flap, except for adding a solid panel between flap and trailing edge. I'm afraid that adding the panel will achieve nothing, except for adding some mass. Since the gap between flap and wing is already filled with separated flow and the space aft of that added panel will also contain separated flow, the aerodynamic effect will be zero. The flow around the wing will look exactly the same, with or without this panel.
